# Converse of the Weierstrass M-Test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I am self-learning real-analysis from the text, *Understanding Analysis*, by Stephen Abbott. I would like someone to verify if my below counterexample to the exercise problem 6.4.2 (c) is valid and technically correct.

> **[Abbott 6.4.2]** Decide whether each proposition is true or false, providing a short justification or counterexample as appropriate.

(c) If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ converges uniformly on $A$, then there exists constants $M_n$ such that $|f_n(x)| \leq M_n$ for all $x \in A$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n$ converges.

***Proof.***

The converse statement is:

$(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ converges uniformly on $A)$ $\implies$ $\{[(\exists M_n)(|f_n(x)|\leq M_n)(\forall x \in A$)]$ \land$ $[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n$ converges$]\}$

Carefully negating this, we have:

$(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ converges uniformly on $A)$ $\land$ $\{\lnot[\cdots]$ $\lor$ $\lnot[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n$ converges$]\}$

Let $(f_n)$ be the sequence of functions defined by:

$$f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n}, \quad x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$$

The infinite series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)=x+\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}\ldots$$

converges uniformly on $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$. To see this, pick an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ and consider:

\begin{align*}
|f_{m+1}(x) + \ldots + f_n(x)| &= f_{m+1}(x) + \ldots + f_n(x) & \{f_n(x) \geq 0\}\\
&= \frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1} + \ldots + \frac{x^n}{n} \\
&\leq \frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1} + \frac{x^{m+2}}{m+1} + \ldots + \frac{x^{n}}{m+1}\\
&\leq \frac{1}{m+1}\left[1+x+x^2+\ldots\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{m+1}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x}\\
&\leq \frac{1}{m}\cdot \frac{1}{1-(1/2)}= \frac{2}{m} & \{x \leq \frac{1}{2}\} 
\end{align*}

Pick $N > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$. Then, $|f_{m+1}(x) + \ldots + f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $n > m \geq N$ and for all $x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$. By the Cauchy criterion for the uniform converge of infinite series, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent.

Moreover, pick $M_n = \frac{1}{n}$. We have:

$$f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n} = M_n$$

for all $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$. But, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is the harmonic series which is divergent.

Comment: Well there's also $M_n=\frac{1}{n2^n}$ which is such that $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert\leq M_n$ for all $x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ and all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n2^n}$ converges.

Comment: I see your point. Is the negation of $p \implies (q \land r)$ equal to $p \land \lnot (q \land r)$? Am I making a mistake with what I need to show? A clue (without revealing the solution) would help.

Comment: You need to show that there exists a uniformly convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ on some set $A$ such that there **does not exist** a sequence $\{M_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ such that the properties $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert\leq M_n$ (for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $x\in A$), and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ converges, **are both true**.

Comment: In your case, you just showed that those properties are not both true for a very particular choice of $\{M_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$, but you need to show that they cannot both be true regardless of $\{M_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$.

Comment: I'm not saying anything on whether it's actually true or not btw

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent on any $[0,a]$ where $a < 1$, so it is uniformly convergent on $[0,1)$. Now, for all sequences $(M_n)$ satisfying $f_n(x) \leq M_n$ for all $x \in [0,1)$, it is necessarily true that $M_n \geq \frac{1}{n}$. Since, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n$ is divergent by the comparison test.

Comment: "...is uniformly convergent for any $[0,a]$ where $a<1$, so it is uniformly convergent on $[0,1)$." This is not a true implication. Uniform convergence on all compact subsets **does not** imply uniform convergence on the entire set.